# LinqKit PredicateBuilder adding to linq query

Tags: linq, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I have a linq query which I want to add some additional, optional `WHERE` conditions to using LinqKit Predicate Builder.  However, I an struggling to get the additional predicate to work

This is my initial query:

```
var query = (from OP in ctx.OrganisationProducts
             where OP.OrganisationID == orgID
             orderby OP.Product.Name, OP.Product.VersionName
             select OP).Include("Product");
```

As you can see, there is `JOIN` in there.
I then wish to add additional predicates if required:

```
if(!includeDisabledP42Admin || !includeDisabledOrgAdmin)
{
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.True<OrganisationProduct>();
    if (!includeDisabledP42Admin)
        pred.And(op => op.Enabled);
    if (!includeDisabledOrgAdmin)
        pred.And(op => op.AccessLevel == "NA" || op.AccessLevel == "NU");
    query = query.Where(pred);
}
```

However, the generated SQL is unchanged and the query returns the same number of rows.

I thought I might have had to do the Expand conversion as so:

```
query = query.AsExpandable().Where(pred);
```

But this causes a runtime error.

I think the issue is the fact that I am adding the predicate to a query that is already *no longer* a pure `OrganisationProduct` object, however I would like advise on how I insert my predicate at the right place.

Thanks and all :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the return value of `And` to the predicate:

```
pred = pred.And(op => op.Enabled);
```

Side note: you may like [this predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) that works without `Expand/AsExpandable`, but has the same syntax.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks!  Amateur mistake.  Each `pred` is presumably immutable then.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the universal PredicateBuilder.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit eager.  Changing the `pred = pred.And` now causes a runtime error: `"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."`

Comment: That's what Expand or AsExpandable is for in Linqkit. But the other predicate builder works without it.

Comment: Thanks @Gert, but I included that first but that returned a different exception `Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable``1' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable``1`

Comment: Looks like Linqkit's PB has some glitches with async, although I can't confirm that. Would you mind trying the other PB?

Comment: Wow!  That worked!  Still not sure why but I've checked the generated SQL and it is what I expected.  Thumbs up to [Universal Predicate Builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).